# Javascript array Prototype find

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, prototype

on developer.mozilla i found an example of working with array find:

```
const inventory = [
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
  {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
  {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function isCherries(fruit) {
  return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(isCherries));
// { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

I have an cart Class with an array of objects, so, i am having a function checkQuantity which should return whatever item satisfies the condition. Also i am having same function where i need to find.

i tried to implement this approach from mozilla, and i did like this:

```
itemSearch(item) {
        return item.id === this.id &&
            item.color === this.color &&
            item.size === this.size
    } // method which i need
```

and i am using it like this:

```
 checkQuantity() {
        return this._cart.find(this.itemSearch()).quantity < this.stockCount();
    }
```

Where i obtain undefined, however i know for sure it must find , because if i use .find(element => conditions) instead of that method, it works.

so, my Question is why it does not work? Sorry for bad english.

Comment: do you have a data set with class and (non)working example?

Comment: Take another look at the example you got inspiration from. They do `.find(isCherries)`, not `.find(isCherries())`

Comment: @blex, my first try was without () , it does not work anyway.

Comment: @iftwMZ, you have to bind to `this` explicitly: `this._cart.find(this.itemSearch.bind(this))`. Otherwise you lose the correct context and `this` will point to `window` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `this`, you need to specify `this` as well for [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), beside not to use the result of the call of the function.

```
checkQuantity() {
    return this._cart.find(this.itemSearch, this).quantity < this.stockCount();
}
```

Comment: Works. thank you so much. Waiting 10 minutes and i mark as answered!